# Audit question for redundant answers does not show previous answers

Tags: discussion, review-audits, late-answers

I just now had the following audit question while reviewing the late answers queue:

*https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/27730706*

It only showed the question and the single (apparently flagged) answer, which was flagged as redundant since it paraphrased other answers. I never got to see these answers, so how am I supposed to detect this as an redundant answer?

I reviewed this audit as "OK", which was in my opinion the right action given that there was only a single answer which was clearly formulated and correct.

Shouldn't at least one additional answer be shown in such cases?

Comment: New answers to questions with lots of votes should always be scrutinized very carefully; these new answers are generally *very unlikely* to provide useful info that other answers don't already cover. `other answers: 9` Click through to the question to check. Also, even were it not for that, the answer is poorly formatted: "No action needed" definitely wasn't the right choice anyway.

Comment: Review queue never shows other answers (related [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174445/241919)), it's up to the reviewer to check other answers manually. Alternatively, use [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch (SOUP)](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) userscript to show other answers on the review.

Comment: “how am I supposed to detect this as an redundant answer?” - By opening the question in another tab.  Audits are designed to be passed.  I routinely open a review question in another tab.  In the future I recommend slowing down or viewing the entire question before choosing “ok” while reviewing late answers. It appears the comment was submitted before you reviewed the answer.  You might slow down in the future.